# MVC en C#, conexión con un servidor para recibir datos en segundo plano

Tags: c#, mvc, asterisk

Buenas, estoy desarrollando un programa que debe conectarse a con un servidor que aloja una centralita **Asterisk** y listar en formato Web una lista con los eventos que esta recibe.

Para ello, estoy haciendo proyecto con el visual studio basado en MVC. Ya tengo hecho el modelo, la vista y en otra solución de aplicación de consola tengo hecho el programa que se encarga de la conexión con la centralita para recibir los eventos. El problema es que no sé cómo integrar este en mi mvc ya que se supone que todo el tiempo que esté ejecutada la aplicación web debe haber un **socket** abierto para poder ir recibiendo los nuevos eventos que surjan en la centralita. No sé si hay alguna forma de utilizar un hilo que esté en segundo plano para hacer esta acción, la verdad que ando un poco perdida.

Dejo el código del programa en C# que conecta con la centralita:

```
namespace Conexion_asterisk
    {

        class AppConsole
        {
            [STAThread]
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Quick Asterisk Test:\n");

                try
                {
                    // Connect to the asterisk server.
                    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP_centralita), 5038);
                    clientSocket.Connect(serverEndPoint);

                    // Login to the server; manager.conf needs to be setup with matching credentials.
                    clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Action: Login\r\nUsername: admin\r\nSecret: password\r\nActionID: 1\r\n\r\n"));

                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    bool authenticate = false; 
                    do
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                        bytesRead = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);

                        Console.WriteLine(bytesRead + " bytes from asterisk server.");

                        string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        Console.WriteLine(response);


                        if (authenticate || Regex.Match(response, "Message: Authentication accepted", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
                        {
                            authenticate = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("NameEvent: "+SearchString(response,"Event"));
                            Console.WriteLine("RemoteAddress: "+SearchString(response, "RemoteAddress"));
                            Console.WriteLine("AccountID: " +SearchString(response, "AccountID"));
                            Console.WriteLine("SessionID: " +SearchString(response, "SessionID"));
                            Console.WriteLine("DataEvent: " +SearchString(response, "EventTV"));
                            Console.WriteLine("Severity: " +SearchString(response, "Severity"));
                            //Console.WriteLine("CriticalityLevel " +SearchString(response,"Event"));
                            //Console.WriteLine("Resolved " +SearchString(response,"Event"));
                        }

                    } while (bytesRead != 0);

                    Console.WriteLine("Connection to server lost.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed connection: " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola Ace.. Tu ejemplo es una aplicacion de consola.. Ahora, olvidandote del mvc, podrias hacer un background worker o un thread que corriera ese programa, pero debes transformalo en un libreria de clases.y desde tu programa principal instanciar eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, la más recomendada, según lo que he visto de los profesionales, sería separar completamente esa aplicación, correrla como una aplicación de consola, separada del servidor web.

Esto sucede por diversas razones, la más sonada es que IIS puede reciclar el pool de conexiones en cualquier momento, cuando esta acción es realizada se levanta una instancia igual a la que esta corriendo en background, una vez que está lista va recibiendo las conexiones nuevas, pero la instancia vieja puede seguir viva por un tiempo indeterminado mientras termina de resolver sus requests, dejando en ciertos tiempos dos instancias corriendo a la vez.

Si usas esas clases como caches, no te afecta mucho, pero como estas usando un socket con un puerto eso te puede afectar pues el puerto aún no estará libre cuando IIS recicla la aplicación (Busca IIS recycle cycle para más información).

También ayuda mucho separar lo que es IIS, tu servidor web de otras partes de la aplicación, si es un socket directo que no necesita nada del stack tecnologico que da MVC no tiene mucho caso meterlo al servidor.

Habiendo dicho esto, si en verdad necesitas correrlo en el mismo servidor, puedes simplemente crear un `Thread` nuevo ya sea desde una acción de controlador o en el app start, el problema es que IIS no te avisará cuando se este cerrando o reciclando la aplicación, por lo que si tienes recursos abiertos te puede pegar.

La otra es generar un objeto `IRegisteredObject` y registrarlo en el IIS, lo que ganas es que el objeto es registrado con el ciclo de vida del IIS, así cuando IIS vaya a cerrar o reciclar, llamará el método `Stop(bool immediate)` con la bandera en false para avisar que esta apagándose, después, si sigue registrado lo volverá a llamar con la bandera en true para avisarle que tiene 30 segundos para acabar el trabajo o será finalizado forzosamente.

```
internal class KolbiNotificationFireForget : IRegisteredObject
    {
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        public KolbiNotificationFireForget()
        {
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this); // Registra el objeto
        }

        public void ProcessAction() //Este método se manda llamar para crear un hilo aparte y correr la función pesada
        {
            Task.Run(() => DoWork());
        }

        public void Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            Logger.WarnFormat("Cancelation initiated in server");
            if (immediate)
            {
                // Should never reach this, there is no natural way for this top take more than 30 seconds
                Logger.WarnFormat("Cancelation forced in server");
            }
        }
        public void DoWork()
        {
            // Has tu proceso pesado o de bloqueo
            HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this); // Libera el recurso
        }
}
```